# Updating status of one field based on multiple conditions from other fields

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a class 'Contract' in which I want to set a status based on the fulfillment of certain conditions. The status is used for making lists and table of contracts based on their status.
For now, I'm thinking the best solution is to split the code into two parts: Conditions that need to be met before updating an object, and conditions for automatic updates.

The first example would be where the user would change the status of a contract from 'PLANNED' to an active contract. In order to do this, the field 'award_date' would have to be filled in before the other possible fields 'signature_date', and 'start_date'. Possible statuses can be 'AWARDED_UNACTIVE' ('signature_date' with a empty or future 'start_date), 'UNSIGNED_ACTIVE' ('start_date' without 'signature_date'). Another example would be that one can only set the status to 'TERMINATED' if the the contract has an active status (planned or expired contracts can not be terminated).

The second example would be if a contract has been active ('start_date' is before today) and the date passes 'end_date'. In these cases I would like 'status' to change to 'EXPIRED' without needing a manual update.

How would I go about to make this? I'm still a beginner, but I'm guessing it would make the code faster if I could eliminate checking all the conditions, and start with the easiest, such as: If status is terminated, then stop the code. Similarly, if status is active, check if expired. If someone can give me a hint or an example to push me in the right direction, I think I'll manage to set up all the conditions for the function(s).

Then the second part of the question:
The contracts can have extensions and amendments that can prolong or change the status. I know I need to do a loop over relevant contracts, but how do I do it?

```
status = (
    ('PLANNED', 'Planned'),
    ('AWARDED_UNACTIVE', 'Awarded, non active'),
    ('UNSIGNED_ACTIVE', 'Unsigned, active'),
    ('ACTIVE', 'Active'),
    ('TERMINATED', 'Terminated'),
    ('EXPIRED', 'Expired'),
)



class Contract(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False) 
    status = models.CharField(verbose_name='Status', max_length=20,choices=status,default='PLANNED')

    # DATES
    registered_date = models.DateField(verbose_name = 'Registered date', auto_now=True, null=False, blank=False)
    modified_date = models.DateField(verbose_name= 'Modified date', auto_now=True, null=True, blank=True)
    award_date = models.DateField(verbose_name = 'Award date', null=True, blank=True)
    signature_date = models.DateField( verbose_name = 'Signature date', null=True, blank=True)
    start_date = models.DateField(verbose_name = 'Start date', null=True, blank=True)
    end_date = models.DateField(verbose_name = 'Original end date', null=True, blank=True)
    termination_date = models.DateField(verbose_name = 'Termination date', null=True, blank=True)

    # Other fields
    
class Amendment(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False) 
    contract = models.ForeignKey(Contract, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    # DATES
    registered_date = models.DateField(verbose_name = 'Registered date', auto_now=True, null=False, blank=False)
    modified_date = models.DateField(verbose_name= 'Modified date', auto_now=True, null=True, blank=True)
    signature_date = models.DateField( verbose_name = 'Signature date', null=True, blank=True)
    start_date = models.DateField(verbose_name = 'Start date', null=True, blank=True)
    end_date = models.DateField(verbose_name = 'Original end date', null=True, blank=True)

class Extension(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False) 
    contract = models.ForeignKey(Contract, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    # DATES
    registered_date = models.DateField(verbose_name = 'Registered date', auto_now=True, null=False, blank=False)
    modified_date = models.DateField(verbose_name= 'Modified date', auto_now=True, null=True, blank=True)
    signature_date = models.DateField( verbose_name = 'Signature date', null=True, blank=True)
    start_date = models.DateField(verbose_name = 'Start date', null=True, blank=True)
    end_date = models.DateField(verbose_name = 'Original end date', null=True, blank=True)
```

So far I have tried a combination of methods and property decorators with no luck.
I have tried searching for similar problems on stackoverflow, but not managed to find something that fits. Tried ChatGPT but that just sent me on a wild goose hunt. Trying to stay away from r/learndjango in solidarity, so no help there.